# Copy text to an external program, click somewhere on the screen, then save a screenshot

Tags: vb.net, automation

I picked vb.net for this question since it's the only prgramming language I am fairly familair with, but if C++ or something else is more suited for this, I am willing to learn something new.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Retrieve text from database (this already works in vb.net) and copy it to clipboard
2. Switch primary screen to the external application I want to work with (example: word or open office)
3. Emulate key-press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Paste text and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again
5. Emulate key-press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then emulate a click on a pre-defined spot on the screen (like 500pixels from left, 740pixels from top).
6. Save screenshot, using a second value from the database as the filename (the naming part should be easy)
7. Emulate another click on another pre-defined spot
8. Repeat for next text in database.

I wouldn't know where to start, though. I guess the most important part of what I'm trying to achieve is; switching focus to an external application and emulate keypresses and mouse clicks on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use http://www.autohotkey.com/

write a console app to get the value from the database

1 - get autohotkey to run the console app and put the return into the clipboard

then continue as described in your list.